# Why is $(q^*v)q = (qq^{*})v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading a book on numerical linear algebra, and they seem to use $(q^*v)q = (qq^{*})v$ where $q$ and $v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n.$ Now, I tried a case in $\mathbb{C}^2$ to convince myself just to see how it works. Indeed, if $q_1, q_2$ and $v_1, v_2$ are the entries of $q$ and $v$, respectively, then

$$(q^*v)q =
\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 \overline{q_1} c_1+q_1 \overline{q_2}v_2\\
q_2 \overline{q_1}v_1+q_2 \overline{q_2}v_2
\end{bmatrix}
=(qq^*)v.
$$

I know there must be an easy way to show this by just manipulating $q, v$, and $q^*,$ but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $q^* v$ is a scalar...

> ...(commutativity and associativity of $\Bbb C$ respectively give that) $$(q^* v) q = q (q^* v) = (qq^*) v .$$ NB commutativity is really needed here. If we instead took $q, v$ to be scalar quaternions, then again $q^* v$ would again be a scalar but the identity would not hold.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not always sure when I can apply commutativity/associativity because when we write $(q^*v)q$ we break the rules a little bit; technically, $q^*v$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, and we are trying to multiply it on the right with an $n \times 1$ matrix, which is undefined. Would you have any comments on that?

Comment: Is this really works? I'm not an algebra-expert, but I don't see why the second equality holds. The first one looks ok, because that's how I'd define the multiplication by scalar from the right.

Comment: @Ovi For any field $\Bbb F$ (if you haven't encountered general fields, just take $\Bbb F = \Bbb C$) There is a natural isomorphism between the space $\Bbb F^{1 \times 1}$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb F$ and the field $\Bbb F$ itself, defined by $\pmatrix{x} \mapsto x$, but usually we just identify these two spaces. But like you say, we can't multiply a $1 \times 1$ matrix on the right by an $n \times 1$ matrix, so for the expression $(q^* v)q$ to make sense in the first place we already need to be thinking of $q^* v$ as a scalar.

Comment: This isn't breaking the rules per se, but we are abusing notation by using the symbol $q^* v$ for two kinds of objects, namely scalars and $1 \times 1$ matrices. But this abuse is justified by the fact that in situations where both interpretations make sense the expression has the same value.

Comment: @Botond Yes, this is just associativity of matrix multiplication---which says that we could just as well (i.e., unambiguously) written $qq^*v$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Associativity